# No Disk I/O utilization stats on New Relic

Tags: newrelic

When I look at Disk I/O utilization chart in Servers area of New Relic (in Overwiew tab) it is empty (0%) and if I click on Disks tab the following message appears:

> No filesystem activity has been recorded for this time window

This happens now that my server is running the Lite/mobile Lite version of New Relic but this happened also since when I installed the PHP agent (on New Relic sign up) on Linux.
Some suggestion on how can solve this problem?

Comment: It might be related to this: http://docs.newrelic.com/docs/server/server-monitor-known-issues#missing-filesystem-statistics